# OpenCV affine matrix to Three.js

Tags: opencv, three.js

I have been struggling for a while now to get an affine matrix created through OpenCV to show matching results in Three.js. I am attempting to align two images. The first image in Three.js is positioned at (0,0,-100). The second image will be at the same depth but will be translated on the X, Y axes and rotated around the Z. I am able apply the affine matrix to the second image using OpenCV's warpPerspective function and get good results, so my data is good. Something is lost in translation.

The OpenCV matrix looks like so:

```
array([[  1.02056477e+00,   9.69874197e-03,  -6.03476069e+00],
       [ -9.69874197e-03,   1.02056477e+00,  -1.29515128e+02],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

To convert this into a 4x4 matrix in Three.js I use am currently using the following operation where 'a' is the 3x3 OpenCV matrix listed above.

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4(a[0],a[1],0,a[2],
                          a[3],a[4],0,a[5],
                          0,0,1,0,
                          0,0,0,1);
```